# Invalid JSON data in request body: Syntax error POST Call Rest API YII2

Tags: json, rest, yii2, yii2-basic-app

When I try to post using Postman,I get this error  `{"name":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid JSON data in request body: Syntax error.","code":0,"status":400,"type":"yii\\web\\BadRequestHttpException"}`

My controller is

`class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Country';

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
           'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
           'only' => ['index', 'view','create'],
           'formats' => ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,],

        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index'=>['get'],
                'view'=>['get'],
                'create'=>['post'],
                'update'=>['put'],
                'delete' => ['delete'],
                'deleteall'=>['post'],
            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```

}`

added

```
'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
```

in **api/config.php** file.

Where I am wrong??

Comment: Are you using PHP7?
I've found that with PHP7 if you send an empty body with content/type=application/json in give an error, but it was working perfectly on previous versions of PHP.

Comment: No Im using PHP 5+

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
           'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
           'only' => ['index', 'view','create'],
           'formats' => ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON]

        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'index'=>['get'],
                'view'=>['get'],
                'create'=>['post'],
                'update'=>['post'],
                'delete' => ['delete'],
                'deleteall'=>['post'],
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: I dont find any difference in my behaviors() and yours :)

Answer (score -1):

I am using wordpress 4.7 on php 7, also getting problems with the empty request body.

My Controller :

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function()
{
     register_rest_route('v0', '/accounts/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9_\-]+)/accounts', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function($request)
        {
            try {
               return 'hello';
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = json_decode($e->getMessage(), true);
                return new WP_Error($error['status_code'], $error['message'], "");
            }
        }
    ));
});
```

Response Error :

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_json","message":"Invalid JSON body passed.","data":{"status":400,"json_error_code":4,"json_error_message":"Syntax error"}}
```

I did not found any solution rather than changing in WP core : wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-request.php and chaning line 672 for conditional check for empty body or not.

```
$params = json_decode( $this->get_body(), true );
```